# My startup application isn't running on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: startup-applications

On my personal computer, I'm having no success getting a custom application to run upon login on Ubuntu 22.04, so I've added some toy examples to 'Additional startup programs', and none of them seems to be in

```
date > startup.date
date > /home/me/startup.date
date > /tmp/startup.date
```

I expect to find a file ~/startup.date after logging in as myself, but it is absent. What's the trick to getting these to work?

(I don't want something to run on every login, as .bashrc or .profile might do.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm confused about what exactly you tried - the examples you give are shell commands, not programs. What exactly are you trying to execute? a script? a .desktop file?

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarity, @steeldriver. Indeed, I'm trying to enter shell commands. I've added a second screenshot for clarity. (Formerly, I had these commands in a shell script with `0775` permissions, and I specified its path in the 'Add Startup Program' modal, but that was similarly ineffective.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @user68186. I find that your instruction works for me. (My real goal is to run a bash script when I'm logged in.)

Comment: Sure thing, @user68186

Comment: Let me know if the answer below worked for you. If it works, consider accepting my answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will indicate that your problem is solved and help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is about a "custom application" failing to work with Startup Application. It is not clear if this "custom application" is a shell script or not. A properly written shell script beginning with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) should work without the `bash -c`  prefix. However, for a shell command like `date`, the example in the question, the bash prefix is needed. The rest of the answer is about the specific example in the question.

## Login log (make Your Own)

The intent is to record and find out when the user logged in. The commands below are to be entered in the **Startup Applications** as indicated in the question. The correct syntax is:

```
bash -c 'date > startup.date'
```

Note, the above command will create or overwrite the file `startup.date` every time the user logs in. It does not record the date and time the computer was started up.

One issue with this command is that it overwrites the file. So only one record is retained. If the intent is to keep a log of every login, then the next command works better:

```
bash -c 'date >> login.log'
```

Note the double greater than sign `>>`. This appends the date to the existing file.

## Login log (system generated)

There is no need to create entries in the **Startup Application** as the system already records login events. This section describes how to access these logs easily from the terminal.

Ubuntu provides a handy command to review system generated login and reboot logs. By default, the `last` command uses the system log file `/var/log/wtmp` as the data source to generate reports. `wtmp` is a binary file on Unix-based operating systems. It keeps a record of all reboot, login and logout activity.

It can display various information, including the date and time of access, the duration of the session, and the device or terminal used to access the system. Running the `last` command without passing any options or specifying a username (or the keyword `reboot`) prints all users that have previously logged in as well as when the computer was rebooted.

```
$ last
redward  :0           :0               Tue Apr 18 09:48   still logged in
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-67-generi Tue Apr 18 09:47   still running
redward  :0           :0               Thu Apr 13 10:51 - crash (4+22:56)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-67-generi Thu Apr 13 10:47   still running
redward  :0           :0               Mon Apr 10 21:59 - crash (2+12:48)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-67-generi Mon Apr 10 21:58   still running
redward  :0           :0               Wed Apr  5 22:33 - down  (4+23:24)
.... truncated ....
```

`redward` is the username who had logged in, in this example.

The first column shows the username of the logged-in user, and the second column shows how the user is accessing the system, for example, via teletype (TTY) or pseudo-terminal. However, it shows “system boot” if it’s a restart task.

The third column shows us where the user logged in from. We should expect to see a hostname or an IP address if the login was from a remote computer, an empty value if it was via teletype, or the kernel version if it’s a reboot task.

Finally, the fourth column shows when the login activity happened, and the fifth column shows the logout time. The last column shows how long the user has been connected in the format “Hours: Minutes“.

If you want to know the login times of the current logged in user (you), open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
last $USER | head -5
```

The `| head -5` part shows the last 5 logins by the current user. You may specify multiple users to find out about last logins by other users of the computer:

```
last barbie ken | head -5
```

See `man last` for various options

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/monitor-login-attempts

Hope this helps